# Passing parameters in functions in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript, event-handling, mean-stack

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-calculator',
 templateUrl: './calculator.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./calculator.component.css']
})

export class CalculatorComponent implements OnInit {
  public result:number=0;
  public num:number=0;
  public final:number=0;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onClick(e){
    this.num = Number(e.target.value);
    this.result = this.num+this.result;
    if(e.target.value == "="){
      console.log(this.result); // the output of console here is : null
      this.display();
    } 
  }

  display(){
      console.log(this.result); // here the console output is : NaN
      this.final = this.result;
  }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <input type="number" value="{{result}}"><br><br>
  <button value="1" (click)="onClick($event)">1</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button value="2" (click)="onClick($event)">2</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button value="=" (click)="onClick($event)">=</button><br><br>
  Result : {{final}}
</div>
```

I want to print the result in the display function but it is not doing so.
even in the onClick() function the result in the if statement is not scopeable.
I want to print the result in the display function

Comment: Please style your code properly, the curly braces are missing.

Comment: Check whether `e.target.value` is equal sign before adding. Right now you are doing it after adding which may end up in `NaN` sometimes.

Comment: i checked that and when i am consoleing normal in if statement it is working properly

Comment: When you press button nr 3 (where value is "="), you will get a NaN because of this `this.num = Number(e.target.value);` => `this.num = Number("=");` => NaN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.num = Number(e.target.value);//Suppose e.target.value is '='
```

You can't convert `=` Symbol to number otherwise you will get NaN

Your code should be as follows

```
onClick(e){
  if(e.target.value == "="){
    console.log(this.result);
    this.display();
  }
 else{
  this.num = Number(e.target.value);
  this.result = this.num+this.result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if condation should be like this :

```
onClick(e){
if(e.target.value !=='='){

  this.num = Number(e.target.value);
  this.result = this.num+this.result;

}else{
  console.log(this.result);
  this.display();
}    }
```

You can check it from :  [Stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6vvmoc)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the order in your onClick method to avoid NaN-exceptions.
You will get a NaN when you try to convert "=" to a number.

```
onClick(e){
    if(e.target.value == "="){
      console.log(this.result); // the output of console here is : null
      this.display();
    } else {
      this.num = Number(e.target.value);
      this.result = this.num+this.result;
    }
  }
```

Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/test-onclick-calclulator)

Answer (score 0):

You should check `if(!isNaN(e.target.value))` at onClick function.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
   public result:number=0;
  public num:number=0;
  public final:number=0;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onClick(e){
    if(!isNaN(e.target.value)){
    this.num = Number(e.target.value);
    this.result = this.num+this.result;

    }
    if(e.target.value == "="){
      console.log(this.result); // the output of console here is : null
      this.display();
    } 
  }

  display(){
      console.log(this.result); // here the console output is : NaN
      this.final = this.result;
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-add